# In my function, "RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in scalar subtract" is raised but I don't know why

Tags: python, warnings

In my simple function, I used try/except with RuntimeWarning raised as an error to see when the warning occurs.

```
def g(x1, z1, x2, z2):
    if x1 == 0 and z1 == 0:
        return 0
    elif x1 == 1 and z1 == 0:
        return z2*(2*x2 - 1)
    elif x1 == 0 and z1 == 1:
        return x2*(1-2*z2)
    elif x1 == 1 and z1 == 1:
        try:
            z2 - x2
        except:
            print(x2, z2)
        return z2 - x2
```

the printed result was 1, 0 which would result simply -1 but when I implemented the function into other algorithm, it sometimes raise an error. Even more annoyingly, when I simple use this function alone, like

```
g(1,1,1,0)
```

which is the exact condition when it resulted an error, it works perfectly fine.

So my question is:

Why RuntimeWarning is raised in this case? Am I missing out something here?
How do I fix it so it does not result a RuntimeWarning? Probably I can use ignore function but I am wondering if there is a different approach.

Here are some more details about the code that the function is used:

```
def rowsum(q, h, i):
    n = q.n
    r = np.copy(q.r)
    x = np.copy(q.x)
    z = np.copy(q.z)    
    
    sig_g = 0
    
    for j in range(n):
        sig_g += g(x[i,j], z[i,j], x[h,j], z[h,j])
    
    indicator = (2*r[h] + 2*r[i] + sig_g)%4
    if indicator == 0:
        q.r[h] = 0
    elif indicator == 2:
        q.r[h] = 1
    
    q.x[h,:] = (x[i,:] + x[h,:])%2
    q.z[h,:] = (z[i,:] + z[h,:])%2
    
# MEASUREMENT 

def MEASURE(q, target):
    n = np.copy(q.n)
    r = np.copy(q.r)
    x = np.copy(q.x)
    z = np.copy(q.z)   
    
    p = np.where(q.x[q.n:-1,1] == 1)[0]
    if p.size > 0:
        # random probability
        p = np.min(p) + n
        
        for i in range(2*n):
            if not i == p and x[i,target] == 1:
                rowsum(q, i, p)
                
        q.x[p-n,:] = x[p,:]
        q.z[p-n,:] = z[p,:]
        
        q.x[p,:] = 0
        q.z[p,:] = 0
        
        q.z[p,target] = 1
        q.r[p] = random.randint(0, 1)
        return q.r[p]
    
    elif p.size == 0:
        # Deterministic outcome
        
        r[-1] = 0
        x[-1,:] = 0
        x[-1,:] = 0
        
        for j in range(n):
            if x[j,target] == 1:
                rowsum(q, 2*n, j + n)   
        return q.r[-1]
```

Comment: _Even more annoyingly, when I simple use this function alone_ This implies that under your real conditions, you're doing something other than "using the function alone".  You'll need to show us that real code.